# Excel Copy Cell Data from one sheet to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I have to copy cell value from one sheet to another. The existing code was

```
'go to the team sheet and select col 3-5 on last row and copy
    Sheets(strname).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 2)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    DoEvents
    'select the col 2 on team line and paste
    Sheets("dtl overview").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
    ActiveSheet.paste Link:=True
    DoEvents
```

The problem is , I have added one more column in the 'team' sheet. So the above copy script has to read one cell backward.

Say for example, the above code is reading the data from D,E & F cells. I dont know how...

I am looking for to change the above code to read the value from C,D&E.

Inputs are Welcome & Highly appreciable!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you consistently copy from columns `D:F` using that code either.
What your code does is:

```
'Activate sheet indicated in the "strname" variable.
'"strName" must be set elsewhere in the code?
Sheets(strname).Activate

'When the sheet is activated a cell will already be selected on there.
'This will be whatever cell was active when the sheet was previously looked at.
'This could easily change if a user selects another cell.

'The "OFFSET" command looks at the same row and ten columns to the left of the ActiveCell.
'If the ActiveCell is not in at least column J (11th column) then this
'will throw an "Application defined or Object Defined error" as it will try and select
'a column before column A.
'The offset cell is then selected - hopefully it will be column D.
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -10).Select

'This will select a range from the ActiveCell plus 2 columns on the same row.
'Hopefully columns D:F
Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 2)).Select

'Copy the selection.
Selection.Copy

'Don't need this line unless other code you haven't included needs it.
DoEvents

'Select the "dtl overview" sheet.
Sheets("dtl overview").Select

'Again, whichever cell was last active on "dtl overview" and select the cell 6 columns to the left.
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select

'Paste a link to the original cells.
'So if you copied D4:F4 on the original sheet (which I'll call "Sheet1") then this will paste
'=Sheet1!D4 , =Sheet1!E4 and =Sheet1!F4
ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

'Definitely shouldn't need this now.
DoEvents
```

At the moment your code looks 10 columns to the left of whichever cell is currently active - so depends which cell you have selected when you run the code.

You don't say which row you want copying, so this code copies row 1 and pastes to cell `D1`.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim strName As String
    strName = "Sheet1"
    
    'ThisWorkbook means the file containing this code.
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strName)
    
    'Cells(1,4) is row 1, column 4.
    'Range(Cells, Cells) shows a start & end cell for the range.
    With wrkSht
        .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(1, 6)).Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dtl overview").Cells(1, 4)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Further reading:  [With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)

Comment: I changed -10 with 11, it is working fine. But i don't know how it internally works.

Comment: The requirement is changed now, for the 4th column, i have to sum(E45:F45) from another sheet and store it in the'dtl overview' sheet.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation of your code. Hopefully it's worded to make it easily understandable.  Your update may merit starting a new thread for a new question, or editing your original question to include the requirement.